# Why does my Button not get the right Onclick event in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have implemented the state pattern for my game in Unity.
Thus I have a main class (BattleSystem) which starts by calling different states.
One of those states is the AttackState. The AttackState has an attackButton which is an UI Button (using UnityEngine.UI).

My State class looks like this:

```
public abstract class State : MonoBehaviour
{
    protected BattleSystem battleSystem;

    public abstract void Tick();

    public virtual void OnStateEnter() { }
    public virtual void OnStateExit() { }

    public State(BattleSystem battleSystem) {
        this.battleSystem = battleSystem;
    }    
}
```

My StateMachine class looks like this:

```
public abstract class StateMachine : MonoBehaviour
{
    protected State state;

    public void SetState(State state) {
        this.state = state;
        state.OnStateEnter();
    }
}
```

The Button is in the BattleSystem class like this:

```
public class BattleSystem : StateMachine
{
    public Button attackButton;
 // Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    SetState(new AttackState(this));
}
```

I dragged the AttackButton object onto my attackButton field in the inspector in the Unity editor.

My AttackState.cs:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class AttackState : State
{

    public AttackState(BattleSystem battleSystem) : base(battleSystem)
    {

    }

    public override void Tick()
    {
        
    }

    public override void OnStateEnter()
    {
       

        Debug.Log("AttackState");
        battleSystem.attackButton.onClick.AddListener(delegate () { this.Attack(); });
        Debug.Log(battleSystem.attackButton.gameObject.name);

    }

    public void Attack() {
        Debug.Log("Attacking");
        foreach (Transform child in battleSystem.cardDropZone.transform)
        {
            Card card = (Card)child.GetComponent("Card");

            // inflict damage to opponent equal to attack of cards   
            if (battleSystem.canDamageBeInflicted(card))
            {
                battleSystem.inflictDamage(card);
                // adjust crystalCount
                TurnUtilities.crystalCount -= card.crystalCost;

                // Move card to graveyard after it has been used
                battleSystem.sendToGraveyard(child);

                battleSystem.attackButton.GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text = "End Turn";

            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log("not enough crystals");
            }
        }

        if (PlayerIsDead())
        {
            battleSystem.isPlayerDead = true;
            battleSystem.SetState(new GameEndingState(battleSystem));
        }
        if (EnemyIsDead())
        {
            battleSystem.isEnemyDead = true;
            battleSystem.SetState(new GameEndingState(battleSystem));
        }
    }


    bool PlayerIsDead()
    {

        if (battleSystem.playerHealthbar.value <= 0)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;

    }


    bool EnemyIsDead()
    {
        if (battleSystem.enemyHealthbar.value <= 0)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

The funny thing is that the `Debug.Log(battleSystem.attackButton.gameObject.name);` works and gives me the name of the GameObject. The event is not being registered though. What did I miss?

Picture of my Scene:

[image: Scene]

EDIT: I found out that this code works:

```
btn.onClick.AddListener(() => Debug.Log("Test"));
```

Putting the method inside does not work? What is happening here :D

Comment: Where does the AttackState object appear in the inspector? What seems suspicious to me is that the `attackButton` variable is defined in BattleSystem, but it is somehow available as well in `AttackState.OnStateEnter`. Where/how is `AttackState.attackButton` defined/initialized?

Comment: It is not initialized anywhere. It is given to the BattleSystem Gameobject which has the BattleSystem class in the inspector. In AttackState.OnStateEnter it is referenced from the battleSystem instance that is being passed from the BattleSystem.cs like this:  battleSystem.SetState(new AttackState(battleSystem));

Comment: @tooomg my bad, I posted a variant where I was trying to debug, I fixed it now to battleSystem.attackButton!

Comment: Alright :) Another question then: do you have an Event System in the scene?

Comment: Yes I do have exactly one EventSystem.

Comment: picture and more info would be more useful to understand your scene and objects! I reckon nothing out of provided code :D

Comment: Added a picture, tell me if you need more @mahdimahzouni

Comment: do this see if it works: this..AddListener(this.Attack());

Comment: Can you try the following? `battleSystem.attackButton.onClick.AddListener(delegate () { this.Attack(); }); `

Comment: or .AddListener(()=>this.Attack());

Comment: @mahdimahzouni this will not work, it will call the function Attack() as soon as the AttackState is created, which is not the desired behavior. You need to create a delegate, like I wrote just above. Edit: the second one does create a delegate and will work :)

Comment: Still does not work. It does not call the function unfortunately. @tooomg

Comment: Could the AttackState have been destroyed between the AddListener call and the click event?

Comment: No, I do not think so. I posted the whole AttackState.cs. It should atleast say "Attacking" when I click on the Button but it does not.

Comment: @tooomg not really actually ... `onClick.AddListener(Attack);` , `onClick.AddListener(() => Attack());` and `onClick.AddListener(delegate () { Attack(); });` are all three synonyms and behave the same/similar way. Actually the first would be the best so you are also able to remove it via `onClick.RemoveListener(Attack);` which is impossible when you use an anonymous delegate or a lambda

Comment: @NuTa do you at any point remove the listeners? You might get into trouble using delegate or lambdas .. it makes it impossible for you to remove listeners (except you use `RemoveAllListeners` ofcourse). You should rather use `onClick.AddListener(Attack);` directly. Is the button click working at all? I mean do interactions work? Does the button get colored on hover and press?

Comment: It gets highlighted, yes. I am really struggling with this. I thought about adding the Listener on another place but tbh the design would be perfect if it would work like this, where I get the button working when my game is in the appropriate state...